# How to custom deepstream python sample with face_recognition library

Tags: python, face-recognition, nvidia-jetson-nano, nvidia-deepstream

---

Hardware: Jetson Nano - Jetpack 4.4 - Python 3.6 - Deepstream 6.0

---

I'm currently working with deepstream-imagedate-multistream.py [1](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/deepstream_python_apps/tree/master/apps/deepstream-imagedata-multistream) example from NVIDIA-AI-IOT repo and I want to use face_recognition library [2](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) (of adam geitgey) in this sample to recognize faces in multiple video sources. So the question is that how can I directly process frames in this sample pipeline.

I have read the deepstream document and have done many tests but still don't have any results.
I hope that anybody have encounter the same problem or having similar experience could help me find a solution. I would really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.